# Use SQL count result in IF statement - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, count

I need to use a result from a COUNT query in an if statement:

```
 $C = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblLinkUserCourse WHERE UserID = $CurrentUserID;");
        if ($C==0)
        {
            echo "You have no courses.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "You have courses.";
        }
```

I'm trying to acheive something as shown above. Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_query()` doesn't return the selected data, you have to call a `mysql_fetch_XXX()` function to get a row of the data.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM tblLinkUserCourse WHERE UserID = $CurrentUserID;");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$C = $row['c'];
if ($C==0)
{
    echo "You have no courses.";
}
else
{
    echo "You have courses.";
}
```

Comment: Ah, I thought it was something like that! In fact, I think I've used this before!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` returns a resource or boolean. Not the query results. add

`$cnt = mysql_result($C,0);` below your query and above your if statement, then use the variable `$cnt` in your IF condition and it should work.

Note: mysql is being phased out, you should move to PDO or mysqli.